# Asp.net MVC, 4.0 - Ajax, field value is overriden after update

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am playing around with some ajax, and have experienced a very odd and to me illogical bug.

I am displaying a list of events, wrapped in a form, in a table. Each event has a unique ID (EventID). This is submitted to the action when a button is pressed.
A div surrounding the table is now updated with the partialview that the action has returned.

**The problem**

When the view is reloaded, all the HiddenFields that contains the field EventID, now cointains the same EventID as. the one that was submitted to the action

I have tried placing a breakpoint in the view, to see what value is put in the HiddenField. Here is see that the correct id is actually set to the field. but when the page updates, all the hiddenfields contains the same eventid as the one originally submitted to the action.

**The partialview: _Events**

```
@model SeedSimple.Models.ViewModelTest

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">

 @foreach (var item in Model.events)
        {
           @using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddAttendantToEvent", "MadklubEvents", new AjaxOptions()
                        {
                            HttpMethod = "post",
                            UpdateTargetId = "tableevents"
                        }))
                {

                    @Html.Hidden("EventID", item.MadklubEventID);            
                    <input type="submit" value="Join!" id="join" class="btn" />                             
                }

           @using (Ajax.BeginForm("RemoveAttendantFromEvent", "MadklubEvents", new AjaxOptions()
                {
                    HttpMethod = "post",
                    UpdateTargetId = "tableevents"
                }))
                {

                    @Html.Hidden("EventID", item.MadklubEventID);

                    <input type="submit" value="Leave" class="btn" />

                }

        }
</table>
```

**AddAttendantToEvent Action:**

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult AddAttendantToEvent(int EventID)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var uow = new RsvpUnitofWork();

                var currentUser = WebSecurity.CurrentUserName;
                var Event = uow.EventRepo.Find(EventID);
                var user = uow.UserRepo.All.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Profile.UserName.Equals(currentUser));
                user.Events.Add(Event);
                Event.Attendants.Add(user);
                uow.Save();
                ViewModelTest viewmodel = new ViewModelTest();
                viewmodel.events = madklubeventRepository.AllIncluding(madklubevent => madklubevent.Attendants).Take(10);
                viewmodel.users = kitchenuserRepository.All;

                return PartialView("_Events", viewmodel);
            }
            else
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

How all the input fields look after having submitted EventID 4 to the action

```
<input id="EventID" name="EventID" type="hidden" value="4">
```

I am suspecting, this is due to some side-effects from the ajax call, that i am unknown to.
Any enlightentment on the subject would be much appreciated :)

Comment: The HTML-Id `tableevents` exists only once on the the page?

Comment: Yes, there is only one element with the id tableevents. It is a <div id="tableevents"> surrounding @Html.Partial("_Events", model); In the main view

Comment: Have you tried to use HTML.HiddenFor instead of HTML.Hidden, looks like you the same name and ID for the input element? Have you check the values of your model before returning in your action?

Comment: Using HiddenFor did not solve anything. Yes, the values of the models are correct when returning. I even outputted the @item.MadklubEventID in each row. This value is correct but inside the input field, the value is NOT correct.. this continues to baffle me

Comment: I solved the problem, by using the regular "html" way of doing it. So instead of using the html helper i just did <input id="EventID" name="EventID" type="hidden" value="@item.MadklubEventID"> I have no idea why the other way didn't work, and i am still very curious.

Comment: Well it's good it works now, but you're right it's bit strange. Maybe I can reproduce it(at the moment I only have my tablet) and if I find a reason I will post it.

Comment: i realized i possibly held out some code, that could give some more insight: namely the RemoveAttendant form. I have updated the  view code

Comment: You can run into this issue when you don't follow the Post-Redirect-Get pattern.  See this link for more info:  http://aspnet.codeplex.com/workitem/5089?ProjectName=aspnet

Comment: That was it! i added a redirect to a get Action, where i initialized the viewmodel and returned it to the partialview. That seemed to solve the problem. If you add an answer i'll accept it